# how to highlight the selection of a top level menu (without selecting)in Flex MenuBar component?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I'm using a mx:MenuBar component in my application for navigating to different views. Say for e.g, **Home | IPL | EPL | ATP** are the top level menus in my MenuBar. The 'Home' menu does not have any pop-up sub menu. By default, when I log on to my application, the 'Home' page has to be loaded which corresponds to the selection of 'Home' menu in the MenuBar. The Home page is loaded. But, it seems like the loaded page is irrelevant without the menu item selection i.e no top level menu is selected. but a page is loaded when I log on.

I want my 'Home' menu in the MenuBar should be highlighted (default) as I log on to the application.

I used `selectedIndex=0` (since 'Home' menu holds the 0th position)in the `mx:MenuBar` component. But then, the highlighting is not happening.

How to do it ? Please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
myMenuBar.selectedIndex = 0;
myMenuBar.menuBarItems[0].menuBarItemState = "itemDownSkin";
```

You can add the above code to your creationComplete handler

Brian